# Calculate indefined integral

Tags: calculus

Could someone check the result of integral: $$\int\frac{x(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x+(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\text{d}x$$

Using substitution: $t^3=x+2$,

I get this solution:

$$\frac{3}{4}(x+2)^{\frac{4}{3}}-\frac{3}{2}(x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\ln|(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1|+2\ln((x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}+2)-\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\frac{(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$$

Is this correct?

$(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is a cube root

Comment: I have tried to cleanup your result - can you please check I got it all right?

Comment: It would help if you showed us your steps in detail so that we don't have to redo the problem for you.  Writing up your solution here would also help you check it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging in your $t$, you also get $dx = 3t^2dt$ which means $$\int\frac{x(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x+(x+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\text{d}x = 3\int\frac{t^6-2t^3}{t^3+t-2}dt$$ Using polynomial division you should get $$\frac{t^6-2t^3}{t^3+t-2} = t^3-t+\frac{t^2-2t}{t^3+t-2}$$ The denominator of the remaining fraction can be factored as $t^3+t-2 = (t-1)(t^2+t+2)$. Combining this with partial fraction decomposition yields $$\frac{t^2-2t}{t^3+t-2} = \frac{-1}{4(t-1)}+\frac{5t-2}{4(t^2+t+2)}$$ Now for some seemingly bizarre coefficient manipulation, notice that $$\begin{align}\frac{5t-2}{4(t^2+t+2)} = \frac{5}{2}\cdot \frac{2t-\frac{4}{5}+0}{4(t^2+t+2)} \\ = \frac{5}{2}\cdot \frac{2t-\frac{4}{5}+(\frac{9}{5}-\frac{9}{5})}{4(t^2+t+2)} \\ =  \frac{5}{2}\cdot \frac{2t+1-\frac{9}{5}}{4(t^2+t+2)} \\ =\frac{5}{2}\cdot \frac{2t+1}{4(t^2+t+2)} +\frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{-\frac{9}{5}}{4(t^2+t+2)} \\ = \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{2t+1}{t^2+t+2} -\frac{9}{8(t^2+t+2)}\end{align}$$ Lastly, we can rewrite $$\frac{9}{8(t^2+t+2)} = \frac{9}{8}\frac{1}{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{7}{4}} \\ = \frac{9}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}\right)^2+1} \\ = \frac{9}{14}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}\right)^2+1}$$ Using the substitution $w = \frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}$, $dw = \frac{16}{49}dt$ we see that $$\int \frac{9}{14}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}\right)^2+1} = \int \frac{63}{32}\cdot\frac{1}{w^2+1} \\ = \frac{63}{32}\arctan(w) \\ = \frac{63}{32}\arctan\left(\frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}\right)$$ So in total we have $$\begin{align}3\int\frac{t^6-2t^3}{t^3+t-2}dt = 3\int t^3-t-\frac{1}{4(t-1)}+\frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{2t+1}{t^2+t+2}+\frac{9}{14}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}\right)^2+1}dt \\ = \frac{3t^4}{4}-\frac{3t^2}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\ln(t-1)+\frac{15}{8}\ln(t^2+t+2)+\frac{189}{32}\arctan\left(\frac{16t}{49}+\frac{16}{98}\right)+C\end{align}$$

Both integrals look roughly the same, although there might be some disagreement on the coefficients of the second natural log and the arctan functions.